# How to convert date stored in YYYYMMDD to datetime format in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in dataframe which is in YYYYMMDD format i want convert into datetime format . How can do in pandas.

```
    Input

20180504   
20180516   
20180516   
20180517   

**Expected Output**

Date         datetime
20180504   04/5/2018 00:00:00
20180516   16/5/2018 00:00:00
20180516   16/5/2018 00:00:00
20180517   17/5/2018 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Input'], format='%Y%m%d')
print (df)
      Input   datetime
0  20180504 2018-05-04
1  20180516 2018-05-16
2  20180516 2018-05-16
3  20180517 2018-05-17
```

If zero times they are not displayed in column, but if convert to list you can see it:

```
print (df['datetime'].tolist())
[Timestamp('2018-05-04 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2018-05-16 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2018-05-16 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2018-05-17 00:00:00')]
```

If input is `csv` file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['Input'])
```

---

If want same format like in question it is possible, but output is strings, not datetimes:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Input'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%d/%m%Y %H:%M:%S')
print (df)

      Input            datetime
0  20180504  04/052018 00:00:00
1  20180516  16/052018 00:00:00
2  20180516  16/052018 00:00:00
3  20180517  17/052018 00:00:00

print (df['datetime'].tolist())

['04/052018 00:00:00', '16/052018 00:00:00', '16/052018 00:00:00', '17/052018 00:00:00']
```